# Using included script in index.html in React components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to use a variable from a library I have loaded in a script tag in my `index.html` for my React components. I've loaded it as normal:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
  <!-- gives me the 'Plaid' library -->
  ...
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
```

However, when I try accessing `Plaid` in my React components, it's undefined. I am confused because if I put in a debugger right before it, I can still access it. For instance, in my `App.js` component, I have:

```
componentDidMount() {
  debugger // can access 'Plaid' here
  Plaid // throws error, 'Plaid' is undefined
}
```

Why is it that `Plaid` throws an error, even though I can access it through the debugger?

Comment: Are you using Webpack?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app, and then testing my code via `npm start`, which I think goes through Webpack before compiling? It's installed as a node module by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Webpack files are bundled separately, separate from the required script. Thus, when you try to access the global variable, it doesn't exist.

You're going to have to customize your Webpack configuration yourself if you want to use `<script>`s. This involves ejecting `create-react-app` and managing everything yourself. **Backup your project before you do this, because after ejecting there's no going back!** First run:

```
npm run eject
```

After ejecting finishes, navigate to the `webpack.config.js` and add a new key to the configuration object:

```
externals: {

}
```

What [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) does is take a global variable declared by a script from a CDN such as Plaid, and allows it to be used as a module in the project. Thus, configure it like this:

```
externals: {
    plaid: 'Plaid'
}
```

This takes the global variable `Plaid` from the CDN and serves it as a module named `plaid`. Then you'll be able to use Plaid after importing it:

```
const Plaid = require('plaid'); //ES5
import Plaid from 'plaid'; //ES2015
```

(None of this is tested, proceed at your own risk). I would much prefer to use an NPM package if it is provided, over a CDN.

Comment: plaid-node is different from the Plaid I'm trying to use. The Plaid I'm trying to use is actually a ["plaid-link" module](https://demo.plaid.com/) on the client-side that then connects to the server-side plaid client.

Comment: @paoliff Hmm. Maybe try the second option? I've never personally heard about the Plaid library, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late but I am answering this here for future users who had trouble doing what was described above.

The excepted answer is **not** the best way of going about integrating Plaid (or any external dependency in  a `<script>` tag). Ejecting a React app should be [avoided](https://medium.com/@tuchk4/why-i-love-create-react-app-e63b1be689a3) when possible.

A better solution is to use the [React built in](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-global-variables) way of accessing the global variable the script loads. You do this by accessing the window object (`window.NameOfYourObject`). In this case it would be `window.Plaid`.

In the context of the above example this would look like

```
this.linkHandler = window.Plaid.create({
   clientName: 'plaid walkthrough demo',
   product: ['transactions'],
   key: 'YOUR KEY',
   env: 'sandbox',
   webhook: this.props.webhook,
   token: this.props.token,
   selectAccount: this.props.selectAccount,
   longtail: this.props.longtail,
   onLoad: this.handleLoad,
   onSuccess: this.handleSuccess,
   onExit: this.handleExit,
 });
```

Having the script in the head works but it is also poor practice. It would be better to load the script with the component using something like [react-load-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script).

Comment: @PratikSinghal sorry to hear that. If you provide more detail on what exactly didn't work I'd be happy to help troubleshoot.

Comment: No worries, got it to work, I was making a small mistake while using your solution.

Comment: Remember to call `this.linkHandler.open()`, otherwise, the popup won't show.